# current_user_can('administrator') not working in custom login

Tags: admin, login, user-roles, capabilities

I am using a custom login form  on a site and I'm having trouble with redirecting admins to the dashboard automatically.

Below is the login function

```
function auth( $username, $password, $redirect ) {
    global $user;

    $credentials = array();
    $credentials ['user_login'] = $username;
    $credentials ['user_password'] =  $password;
    $credentials ['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $credentials , false );

    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
    {
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    }

    $admin_url = home_url('wp-admin');

    if ( !is_wp_error($user) )
    {
        if (current_user_can('administrator'))
        {
            wp_redirect($admin_url);
        }
        else
        {
            wp_redirect($redirect);
        }
    }
}
```

When I log in as the admin, `current_user_can('administrator')` is returning `false`.

If I step into the `current_user_can()` function, `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` seems to fetch some data, but looks like it's not getting everything, hence the `false` response.

I also tried using `is_admin()` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current user may not be set at this step then try this :

```
    if (user_can($user, 'administrator'))
    {
        wp_redirect($admin_url);
    }
```

Comment: Works, lovely :) Wodner why the current user isn't setup despite using wp_signon()?

Comment: current user is based on the cookie which doesn't exist. it exist only on reload of a page